# Is there an Inspector for Outlook 2013 (or Outlook generally)?

Tags: html, ms-word, outlook, rendering, markup

I'm writing a newsletter campaign which I'm testing in a number of browsers, one of which is Outlook 2013.

I understand how to address specific issues (e.g. http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/horizontal_spacing_issues_in_outlook_2007_and_2010) but what's frustrating me is that I'm having some difficulty understanding what markup is being generated. Currently I'm debugging this by adding background colours to my markup, which is somewhat helpful but not ideal. For example, I can add a background-color using the inline stylesheet for the `<p>` tag to see if Outlook is adding this kind of markup. The limitation of this is that I have to anticipate this kind of behavior and it can be unpredictable. Speaking from experience I suspect that Outlook is using proprietary markup/rendering (the Word rendering engine?) in this version of Outlook (e.g. see http://fixoutlook.org/). Please correct me if this is not the case.

What would be really helpful is the ability to inspect the markup that is being generated. I know that I can inspect the email source by going to *Message* > *Actions* > *Other Actions* > *View Source*, however this appears to be the raw source before it is garbled by Outlook. Specifically I don't see any of this when I inspect the source in this manner.

What I really want is some way to inspect the source of the email as Outlook is presenting it, e.g. something like the inspector that can be accessed by hitting *f12* in many browsers. Does something like this exist. Otherwise, assuming that I'm correct about the garbling of the source (adding markup etc.) is there a way to view the source as Outlook is actually presenting it?

Comment: As an aside, does anyone think a Stack-Exchange site for email-marketing/markup is a good idea?

Comment: RE: @aaron-newton The closest thing is a proposal for [Sales & Marketing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110851/sales-and-marketing). It would be good, but doesn't seem very technical (yet).

Comment: Hello Gregory. I'm aware of several tools which show the message rendered in various email clients via a web based UI, but they're usually bound to some sort of commercial email platform - I'm yet to see an actual debugger. Since I asked this question many new email clients have come out and I mostly send emails using SAAS based services which handle the email templates, so it's not an issue that's directly affecting me.